# multiple Timers in windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer

Im trying to create a little game in c# visual studio 2010.
Im trying to make something like the game Bubble Trouble in windows form applications.

I created a form with 3 timers from the toolbox.
One for the movement of the player(he moves its legs by changing the image of the label)- this timer is set to enabled on event OnKeyDown, and stop on event onKeyUp.

The second timer for the shoot-this timer set to enabled on event "onKeyPress" when the space key is get pressed. And this timer is used to draw the shoot line piece by piece.

And the third timer is for the ball that the player should pop- this timer always running and it propuse is to move the ball around.

But the problem i found is that when i increase the Interval of the ball timer- then when the other timers set to enabled they all get very slow.

What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code?  You may want to check out `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  I'm not sure if the WinForms namespace timer has some weird limitation like you're describing...

Comment: Have you experienced lag during increasing the interval of the ball timer? This also can be caused by high memory cost.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest re-factoring your code a bit, as follows:

1. rather than enabling and disabling timers in the keydown and keyup events, change the value of module level state variables.

For example:

The keydown for the shoot key may do:

```
_shootKeyDown = True
```

The keyup for the shoot key may do:

```
_shootKeyDown = False
```

You can then process all the elements that need to be updated in a single timer event that happens at whatever interval you want.

```
If _shootKeyDown Then
    ...
End If

If _playerDirection <> "" Then
    ...
End If

If _ballExists Then
    ...
End If
```